# Synchronize music ratings between iTunes and Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, itunes, windows-explorer, windows-media-player, metadata

I want to synchronize my file ratings between iTunes and Windows Explorer. I have found one utility--[Orzeszek Ratings](http://www.orzeszek.org/dev/ratings/)--that synchronizes between iTunes => Windows Media Player => iTunes. However, it does not appear to write the ratings to the file; which is how Windows Explorer will pick up on them.

Can anyone suggest another solution to make my carefully specified music ratings visible in Explorer?

Comment: Correction: The utility actually worked. But only for my .mp3 formatted files. The larger part of my music collection is in .m4a, which was not updated.

Comment: Maybe ask the developer if they have any plans to include this type of file in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

You could try out [Music Bridge](https://sites.google.com/site/jrmwillis/).

*"MusicBridge allows people who use both iTunes and WMP on the same machine to keep their libraries in sync. MusicBridge offers a variety of synchronization options so that you can 
manage your music collection in either media player or both."*

This will synchronise your metadata in both directions between Windows Media Player and iTunes.